# Sort column data in dojo datagrid when multiple fields are set to "_item"

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo DataGrid populated by an ObjectStore in which 4 columns represent the data from child objects.

Using advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115518/json-child-object-with-dojo-data-objectstore), I am able to access and display the data in my grid.  Is there a better way to access child data?

As it says in the [dojo documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/populating_datagrid/) (I'm using 1.8, but the issue is the same),

> "By using get, fields, or field set to "_item", the DataGrid will not be able to sort your data. If you need sorting and advanced calculations client-side, you will need to transform the data before it gets to your store."

My question is:  How do I transform the data, and what am I transforming it to?  Does this affect how editing is done on these columns as well?